# Increment Regression Models

Tags: tables, xtable, bullets

I often show regressions tables during presentation and I was wondering if there is a simple way to `increment` regression models.

For instance, I would like to first display model 1 `(1)` and then increment (`M2`).

[image]
[image]

Do you have any idea how I could simply do that?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcc} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cline{2-3} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Inc} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)\\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Age & 73.77$^{*}$ & 56.36 \\ 
    & (28.91) & (29.99) \\ 
    & & \\ 
    Ch &  & $-$77.74$^{*}$ \\ 
    &  & (37.00) \\ 
    & & \\ 
    Constant & 291.85$^{***}$ & 314.77$^{***}$ \\ 
    & (18.77) & (21.66) \\ 
    & & \\ 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & 569 & 569 \\ 
    R$^{2}$ & 0.01 & 0.02 \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.05; $^{**}$p$<$0.01; $^{***}$p$<$0.001} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to be using something like `Age & 73.77$^{*}$ & \uncover<2->{56.36} \\ 
& (28.91) & \uncover<2->{(29.99)} \\ `

Comment: yes exactly thanks. Is there a way to automate this for a whole column? thanks

Comment: There is `\newcolumnstyle` from [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) which could in principle be used for that but I couldn't get it working on a first attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able, using `array` to manage something like what you did. I basically created a new `O` column which in its declaration starts and ends an `uncover` environment, which is uncovered only in the second slide.

Please mind that I substituted the double rules with the top and bottom rules defined by `booktabs`: your table is already finely typeset, but I think that this way it looks a bit better. Please feel free to throw that away!

code:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\uncoverenv<2>}c<{\enduncoverenv}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{table} \centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcO} 
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Inc} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)\\ 
    \midrule \\[-1.8ex] 
    Age & 73.77$^{*}$ & 56.36 \\ 
    & (28.91) & (29.99) \\ 
    & & \\ 
    Ch &  & $-$77.74$^{*}$ \\ 
    &  & (37.00) \\ 
    & & \\ 
    Constant & 291.85$^{***}$ & 314.77$^{***}$ \\ 
    & (18.77) & (21.66) \\ 
    & & \\ 
    \midrule \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & 569 & 569 \\ 
    R$^{2}$ & 0.01 & 0.02 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.05; $^{**}$p$<$0.01; $^{***}$p$<$0.001} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

First slide:

[image]

Second slide:

[image]

**EDIT**

If you have many columns to appear each one from a slide onwards you have two ways of doing that:
1. Define for each slide a column (as the O before) which will have `>{\uncoverenv<x->}` where x is the slide you want to start show it.
2. define a generic column type, e.g. `\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\uncoverenv<#1->}c<{\enduncoverenv}}` which will take, as an argument, the slide from which it will show.

Ie:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\uncoverenv<#1->}c<{\enduncoverenv}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{table} \centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcN{2}N{3}} 
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-4} 
    \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Inc} \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2)&(3)\\ 
    \midrule \\[-1.8ex] 
    Age & 73.77$^{*}$ & 56.36&x \\ 
    & (28.91) & (29.99)&x \\ 
    & & \\ 
    Ch &  & $-$77.74$^{*}$&x \\ 
    &  & (37.00)&x \\ 
    & & &\\ 
    Constant & 291.85$^{***}$ & 314.77$^{***}$ &x\\ 
    & (18.77) & (21.66) &x\\ 
    & & &\\ 
    \midrule \\[-1.8ex] 
    Observations & 569 & 569 \\ 
    R$^{2}$ & 0.01 & 0.02&x \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{3}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.05; $^{**}$p$<$0.01; $^{***}$p$<$0.001} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

will show the third column from the second slide, and the fourth column from the third slide on.

Comment: yes sure, I am just waiting to see if anything else is coming up. thank you very much

Comment: @giacomoV it was meant with no pressure, just a reminder :)

Comment: your solution works fine for two columns but I can't make it work for more columns. Any idea how to do it for 4 or 5 columns? thank you

Comment: @giacomoV what do you need for more columns? For them to show in the same slide or each one will have to render from a specific one?

Comment: @giacomoV works fine for me with any number of columns. I entered a remark though